# JQuery not running correctly on document.ready();

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have placed this inside of my jsp file:

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#resrcTypesTree').height(jQuery('.secondColumn').innerHeight() - 10);
    });
</script>
```

If I run this directly in Chrome's console, it works with no problems.  If I load the page, the #resrcTypesTree id is set to 10px (a css default).  I cannot figure this out as to why it appears to not be setting the height of the resrcTypesTree to the secondColumn's height.  Is there something else that I am missing?  I could put in a pause to check the page after a unit of time goes past, I just feel that is hacky.

The $ for jQuery is being overridden by another library in the project that is why I called jQuery instead of the '$'.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?  Thank you in advance!

- RR

Comment: is `jQuery('#resrcTypesTree')` loaded dynamically ?

Comment: And does `secondColumn` contain images or other dynamic data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an ajax issue.  I had to write a mediator function since there are more than one ajax call being ran.  95% of the time the re-size works once put into the ajax script, however the 5% of the time, the secondary ajax call would get done first, causing the page not to re-size the gradient correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending content you are targeting but as a simple fix, you should wait all content to be loaded:

```
jQuery(window).on('load',function () {
    jQuery('#resrcTypesTree').height(jQuery('.secondColumn').innerHeight() - 10);
});
```